# How can I get the index of an iterator/map state in AWS step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to create a step function that creates an array of results in a map state.
My code looks something like that:

```json
"MyIterator": {
   "Type": "Map",
   "InputPath": "$.myArray",
   "Iterator": {
     "StartAt": "Parser",
     "States": {
       "Parser": {
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "${my-lambda}",
         "ResultPath": "$.Result",
         "End": true
     }
  }
}
```

I want my step function to go through the array I provided, and create an array as the result, but I'm not sure how to do it.
For example, if my lambda will be the function: `x = x + 1` and the input is `myArray = [0,1,2]`, the result will be `Result = [1,2,3]`. Something I thought of is to access the index of the iteration in my `Parser` stage. For example, use `"ResultPath": "$.Result[i]"` if `i` is the index of the iteration.
Is that possible in AWS step functions?
I know I can create another lambda that acts as a counter, I just don't really want to add another one as it looks way over complicated for such a usecase.

I tried to use the above code, but the iteration seemed to override the parameter `Result` each time.

Comment: That would mean that You want to process the records synchronously. Map is actually intended to perform the iterations in parallel. Or do You want to set the concurrency to 1? Here the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html

Comment: I do want to perform it asynchrously. I don't care about the order of the items in the result, I just want each iteration to add its result to an array, which will be processed in another place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Map item index is available on the [Context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map) as `$$.Map.Item.Index`.  The [ItemSelector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-inline.html#itemselector) field<sup>*</sup>, which overrides the values passed to each Map iteration, can reference the Context object:

```json
"MyIterator": {
   "Type": "Map",
   "InputPath": "$.myArray",
   "Iterator": {
     "StartAt": "Parser",
     "States": {
       "Parser": {
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "${my-lambda}",
         "ResultPath": "$.Result",
         "End": true
     }
  },
  "ItemSelector": {
    "ContextIndex.$": "$$.Map.Item.Index",
    "ContextValue.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
  },
}
```

Using your example `myArray = [0,1,2]`, the first iteration would receive:

```json
{ "ContextIndex": 0, "ContextValue": 0 }
```

---

* `ItemSelector` replaces the deprecated `Parameters` field, which did the same thing.  Note also that [ItemProcessor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-inline.html#itemprocessor) has replaced the deprecated `Iterator` field.  They all still work, though.

Comment: How does this work when map is actually working asynchronous? In my understanding when eg. 10 records start processing at the same time they have 0 as starting iterator, evry call adds 1 to the starting 0 and in the end the output is 1. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ExceptionNotThrownException I don't understand your question, sorry. Perhaps the first link in the answer, [Context Object Data for Map States](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map), might help.

Comment: Ah yes, I got this. In one map state each item has an index. Is there a chance to get the output in the same order as from before the processing? Some time ago I was playing with the map state and the output was not deterministc because of the ordering.

Comment: Thanks for this comment clarifying how can I access the index!
However, when I try to use it in the `ResultPath` I still get errors.
I tried to use: 

`ResultPath": "States.format('$.Result[{}]', $.ContextIndex)"`

Comment: That's expected.  The `ResultsPath` field [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions-states) intrinsic functions.

Comment: From @fedonev comment I understood that I'm looking at it the wrong way, so eventually what I did is use the above step function definition to insert a new item at each part of the original array.
In my real use case I had the full input like `{'myArray: [{'index': 0}, {'index':1}, {'index':2}]}`.
I used the step function to add to each item in the array the result, so for example the first one became `{'index':0, 'result':1}`, then I iterated over the results only.